# How to force windows 8 touch keyboard to be displayed on the app screen in a winjs application?

Tags: html, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs, multitouch-keyboard

Am working on a windows store winjs application and am trying to force display the touch keyboard on the application screen.

I couldn't find any proper solution over the net for the same.

Is there a way to force display it?(would be great if there are some work arounds)

Comment: Set focus to the input element.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119178/how-do-i-hide-virtual-keyboard-for-select-element-in-win8-javascript-app/17120615#17120615) might help.

Comment: please refer<http://loekvandenouweland.com/index.php/2013/05/close-winrt-virtual-keyboard-programatically/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The touch keyboard show & hide behavior is designed to be controlled by the user and should not be changed easily.

Anyway an easy workaround is to set the focus on an input control in the page programmatically. This will make the keyboard appear, but the the control will be back to the user and he will be able to hide it at any time.

Cheack this article for a more complex workaround if you need a bit more control: [How do I hide virtual keyboard for select element in Win8 JavaScript app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119178/how-do-i-hide-virtual-keyboard-for-select-element-in-win8-javascript-app/17120615#17120615)